# Syntax highlighting for uppercase headings using === or --- syntax

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-markdown

In Vim, without using any markdown plugin, headings like

```
# Uppercase heading

# lowercase heading

lowercase heading
=================

lowercase heading
-----------------
```

get highlighted, while headings like

```
Uppercase heading
=================

Uppercase heading
-----------------
```

do not get highlighted. *(Actually the `---`s get highlighted, but not the text above them. However, the `===`s stay in the unhighlighted color.)*

I want to know why the headings with the `===`/`---`-syntax starting with an uppercase character do not get highlighted and what can be done to fix it.

Example screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Is filetype detection on? Is the file being identified as markdown? If both of those are true then all of  the above should be considered headers. I just verified it.

Comment: Yes, filetype detection is on and it's being identified as markdown. How do you mean you verified it? Do you not get the same results as the screenshot I just posted?

Comment: I use a different theme so it wouldn't look like that but it looks right. More importantly running this with the cursor over the text in question gives the right value `:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")`  Example: `markdownH2`.

Comment: You are right, and I found that the problem was because I had configured my spellchecker in a hacky way to highlight non-capitalized words. Thank you for the help to figure this out.

Comment: You're welcome. Cheers.

Comment: Please post a self answer with what fixed it for you (more specifically, the configuration you had in your vimrc that was breaking it) and also which steps led you to find the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed with @filbranden; the post can stay if the Q demonstrates the broken configuration and the A addresses how to fix it. Why it breaks would be good too.

Comment: nijoakim, I've rolled back your edit. Answers belong in answers which are found below. Self-answering/accepting is allowed and even encourage. Please do _not_ edit your question to indicate a solution/answer/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported by the OP, this problem does not occur if they delete their vimrc file. The issue arose because of how they had configured the spell checker to highlight capitalized words in beginnings of sentences. This question has thus been resolved.

Comment: Not that I have any particular vested interest, but why didn't this one get closed for the "can't reproduce or user mistake" reason (or as I refer to it, the "oops" category ;)